# Running sudo command using paramiko on remote box

Tags: python, ssh, sudo, paramiko

I have never posted so let me know if I need any more information.  I have been working on a python script to log into a remote linux box and do some filesystem investigation for me.  I have a very strange issue where every once in a while, it will write the password that was used for the sudo command into the stdout a good amount of times.  I'm not exactly sure how to replicate it, as it is pretty random, but it does seem to happen more often on a remote box I have never ran it against.  Here is the program.  You will just need to change the IP field to whatever you are trying to run against.  I kept the commands very simple to make sure it works with all distros.  This will not be the final version of the program, as it is very sloppy, so don't kill me for ugly formatting.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Testing filesystem information using python

import paramiko
import getpass

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
IP = 'hostname'
port = '22'
username = raw_input("Please enter your username:")
password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Please type your password:')
ssh.connect(IP, port, username, password)
transport = ssh.get_transport()
session1 = transport.open_session()
session1.get_pty()
dfdata= """df -m
"""
session1.exec_command('df -m')
while True:
    if session1.recv_ready():
        dfdata += session1.recv(65536)
if session1.exit_status_ready():
        break
        session1.close()
session2 = transport.open_session()
session2.get_pty()
dudata = """sudo du -amx /home | sort -nr | head -15
"""
session2.exec_command('sudo du -amx /home | sort -nr | head -15')
while True:
    if session2.recv_ready():
        dudata += session2.recv(65536)
        if session2.send_ready():
            session2.send("%s\n" % password)
    if session2.exit_status_ready():
        break
        session2.close()
transport.close()
ssh.close()
print "\ndf Results:\n%s\n\ndu Results:\n%s" % (dfdata, dudata)
```